# wcf security token service on https

Tags: wcf, wif

I have started the WCF security token service template in Visual Studio. I get all things up and running over http. So now I have an STS, a WCF Service and I can call GetData(int) with the WCFTestClient. This is running on http.

Now I want to run the STS on https. So I've added it to IIS and added an https endpoint. If I browse to the sts it works on https now.
Next I create a WCF Service, add an sts reference etc. I add this WCF Service to IIS too, on https.
And the last step I create a console app, but then when I call the WCF service Cardspace is started and I get an error. First problem: I don't want Cardspace to start, and it shouldn't start as far as I know. Second: the error message is 'incoming policy failed validation'.

What are the steps to run the STS on https? Is there a tutorial?
Does anyone else finds this a familiar situation, and knows a solution?

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: The error message is 'incoming policy failed validation'. But actually  I don't want Cardspace to start at all, and it shouldn't start as far as I know.

Comment: I guess I'll try WIF in 5 years or so. When hopefully the tooling is a lot better. Claims Based Identity is a great concept, but it looks like it's too early to be implemented by a simple developer.

Comment: @Thomas: Sounds like you have configured your IIS to require a client certificate (in the ssl settings of your site).

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem of cardspace starting myself and after checking the wif configuration several times I found some error in the config. After fixing the config error, everything worked.

Sorry that I could be more spesific one the error (too long ago). But be very, very sure that you have configured your sts and wcf correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try specifying the following: in your config under message.

```
<issuer address="stsurl" binding="ws2007HttpBinding"
                            bindingConfiguration="stsbindingconfig">
   <identity>
        <userPrincipalName value="fqnofUpn" />
    </identity>
 </issuer>
```